# Multiple databases, possibly creating a loop?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following code below...the query works, but I'm looking for a better way to search though an entire column for a specific criteria.  I think my question is going to require a loop, I'm just not sure how to perform it.

The last line of code states '

> Where [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt].[sTxt] like '%258912.pdf

The value **258912.pdf** is the value in

> [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[IDEA Project Tracker].[Filename]

I would like to try and create a method where the query reads one value in **sTxt**, then compares the whole column to **Filename**.  If it finds the value, then display **sTxt**, if not, go to the next value in **sTxt** and begin searching each value in **Filename**.

Please let me know if you need additional information. Thanks in advance.

```
Select  [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt].[nItemId]
  , [sTxtType]
  , [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems].[nUrlId]
  , [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_Urls].[sUrl]
  , [sTxt]
  , [Filename]
  , [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt].[vUpdateDt]
From [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt]
Left Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems] on [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt].[nItemid] = [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems].[nItemid]
Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_Urls] on [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems].[nUrlId] = [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_Urls].[nUrlId]
Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[IDEA Project Tracker] on [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems].[nUrlId] = [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[IDEA Project Tracker].[UrlId]
Where [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt].[sTxt] like '%258912.pdf'
```

Comment: Are you having difficulties due to the tables being in different databases?

Comment: Are you still having difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it ought to be possible to do this:

```
select  itemTxt.[nItemId]
      , [sTxtType]
      , idwItems.[nUrlId]
      , urls.[sUrl]
      , [sTxt]
      , [Filename]
      , itemTxt.[vUpdateDt]
From    [dbIdwWhseLC].[dbo].[tbItemTxt] as itemTxt
  Left Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_IDWItems] as idwItems
      on itemTxt.[nItemid] = idwitems.[nItemid]
  Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[tbl_Urls] as urls
      on idwItems.[nUrlId] = urls.[nUrlId]
  Join [IDEAUrlBot].[dbo].[IDEA Project Tracker] projTracker
      on itemText.[nUrlId] = projTracker.[UrlId]
Where  itemTxt.[sTxt] like '%258912.pdf'  -- not sure you intend this to remain
  and  projTracker.[FileName] = itemTxt.[sTxt]
```

But that's so simple that there must be some aspect to what you're looking for that's not clear to me.

Do you want to stop searching after you find a match between `[FileName]` and `[sTxt]`? If you want to return exactly one record, you can just change the first line to

```
select top 1 itemTxt.[nItemId]
```

... and add an ORDER BY clause to the end to control how the results are sorted and therefore which one is the "top 1".

Do you need to use wildcards when matching `[FileName]` and `[sTxt]`?  It's not clear to me from the description which column would have the full path (or file name) and which would have just "258912.pdf", but you could change my last line to:

```
itemTxt.[sTxt] like ('%' + projTracker.[FileName])
```

If you need something more complex, like the first record from `itemTxt.[sTxt]` that matches `projTracker.[FileName]` for every record in `projTracker`, please say so in the comments.

If none of this is along the lines of what you need, you'll need to elaborate on what it is you *do* need.  Please add more detail to your question, such as an example of what the output should look like or what you plan to do with it.